# how to know my host php5 is running under suphp

Tags: php, apache

how to know my php5 is running under suphp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *don't* have the POSIX extension installed (it's not common on shared hosting), one option is going to be creating a new file and then checking the `uid`/`gid` it's created with:

```
file_put_contents('./tmp.txt', 'Stuff!');
echo "File UID is: ", 
     fileowner('./tmp.txt'), 
     ', GID is: ',
     filegroup('./tmp.txt');
```

Now, the numbers alone might not be useful, but they can serve as guidelines.

If the UID is 99, the user PHP is running as is `nobody`, which means no suPHP.  If the UID is 33, that could be user `www-data`, which again means no suPHP.

If the UID is just a few over <s>9000</s> 500 or 1000, then there is a small chance that you're under suPHP.  If it's *way* over 500 or 1000, then you may well be under suPHP.

You *might* be able to actually read `/etc/passwd` and examine the UIDs there, but that's rude.

However, your **best bet** might be checking `phpinfo`.  suPHP might leave clues that it's running, or there might be other environment variables that you can take a peek at.  For example, Apache's `mod_php` can not possibly be suPHP, so if you see that PHP is running as `mod_php`, you certainly aren't suPHP'd.

Answer (score 3):

You can find out under which userid the current script runs with:

```
print_r( posix_getpwuid(posix_getuid()) );
```

This will tell you if it is `apache`/`www-data` or a specific user account.